# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable (install)

Tags: python-3.x, windows-installer

When installing the package with the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

I stumble upon the following error:

```
    C:\Users\qadmin>pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.p", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\run.py",  line 85, in _run_code 
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in (module)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

[image]

I get the same error when I install another module. e.g. numpy, maybe that narrows down the problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you try it with syntax like this?
python (or python3) -m pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

Comment: This works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I take it that the solution I gave, works

```
python (or python3) -m pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

If yes then can you mark this as accepted answer ?